# Find device from serial info

Tags: toit

I have a device that I can't find in the web-console.

Is there a way to find the device in the web-console given the `toit serial info` output?

I currently have:

```
ᐅ toit serial info 
{
        "name": "fd5642de-ac18-4df0-866d-8b5b4a07865c.378.2020-11-10.device.toitware.com",
        "model": "esp32-4mb",
        "hardware_id": "fd5642de-ac18-4df0-866d-8b5b4a07865c"
}
```

I'm not sure the device is claimed, (or, if claimed, in the organization I'm looking in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: it is possible to search for the hardware ID in the name filter.

(The reason it didn't work initially was that I was searching in the wrong organization).

Comment: Exactly, you can search for the hardware id. Unfortunately there is no way to find a not yet claimed device in the Console, as it will not appear in the Console until it is claimed.